# Fetch rows from postgres database from JSON datatype particular value

Tags: php, mysql, postgresql, codeigniter

Hi im having a problem from extracting rows from Json column.
    Below is the json data from which if I want to extract rows say from the value as MH.

This below data is in each rows. So I need a codeigniter query were if I query MH of this applicability column need to fetch rows.
    Can you please help me out with this:

Below is the JSON data:`["AP","AR","AS","BR","CT","GA","GJ","HR","HP","JK","JH","KA","KL","MP","MH","MN","ML","MZ","NL","OR","PB","RJ","SK","TN","TG","TR","UT","UP","WB","AN","CH","DN","DD","DL","LD","PY"]`

```
$this->select('guid, applicability, name, type, description,
        service_type, scheme_type, mini_description, tags, benefit');
        $this->join('schemes_lang_1', 'schemes_lang_1.scheme_id=scheme_1.id', 'left');
$this->where('lang', $lang);
$this->where('status', $status);
$this->where('scheme_1.pp_enabled', 1);
$this->where('scheme_1.applicability', 'MH');
return $this->findAll();
```

The table structure is posted below.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

The given below is row query and you can use this query as a reference and add as much conditions you want

```
SELECT
  guid, 
  applicability, 
  name, 
  type, 
  description,
  service_type, 
  scheme_type, 
  mini_description, 
  tags, 
  benefit
FROM scheme_1
LEFT JOIN schemes_lang_1 ON schemes_lang_1.scheme_id=scheme_1.id
WHERE
  (scheme_1.applicability)::jsonb ? 'MH';
```

Also you can do check condition by json keys like 
If json is like this

```
["company":"AP","Detail":"test"]
```

use `(scheme_1.applicability->'company')::jsonb ? 'AP';`

IN Codeignitor you can do it like this

```
$this->select('guid, applicability, name, type, description,
service_type, scheme_type, mini_description, tags, benefit');
$this->join('schemes_lang_1', 'schemes_lang_1.scheme_id=scheme_1.id', 'left');
$this->where('lang', $lang);
$this->where('status', $status);
$this->where('scheme_1.pp_enabled', 1);
$this->where('(scheme_1.applicability)::jsonb ? ', 'MH');

return $this->findAll();
```

NOTE : Its much faster then using loop and then search one by one record inside the table field and looping search may increase time and space complexity of code by 1000 times.

Answer (score -1):

visit the below site

visit http://www.postgresqltutorial.com/postgresql-json/

then change your code from

```
$this->select('guid, applicability, name, type, description,
service_type, scheme_type, mini_description, tags, benefit');
$this->join('schemes_lang_1', 'schemes_lang_1.scheme_id=scheme_1.id', 'left');
$this->where('lang', $lang);
$this->where('status', $status);
$this->where('scheme_1.pp_enabled', 1);
$this->where('scheme_1.applicability', 'MH');
return $this->findAll();
```

to

```
$query = $this->db->query("YOUR POSTGRES QUERY");

foreach ($query->result_array() as $row)
{
  echo $row['guid'];
  echo $row['applicability'];
  echo $row['name'];
}
```

Comment: this does not really use the benefits of SQL and postgresql jsonb. looping too should be avoided